# My span won't delete or not getting targetted

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why my span isn't getting deleted when all others is behaving like they supposed. Here's my function.

```
const item = e.target;

if (item.classList[0] === 'trash-btn') {
    // this works
    const task = item.parentElement.parentElement;
    task.classList.add('vanish');
    task.remove();
}

if (item.classList[0] === 'text-duedate') {
    // this is not working
    item.remove();
}

if (item.classList[0] === 'check-btn') {
    // this works
    const task = item.parentElement.parentElement;
    completed.appendChild(task);
    item.remove();
    completed.addEventListener('click', statusCheck);
}
```

The div that I am targeting:

```
<div class="card-date">
    <span class="text-duedate">Due: </span>
    <span class="alert">9/12/22</span>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try using `item.classList.contains('className')` instead of taking the first class and checking against it.

Comment: [Can't reproduce the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/140ro8pg/) Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Ivar, https://jsfiddle.net/delo2795/fpt06eyv/3/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `text-duedate` class is not the first class in the `classList`, I suggest to use `contains`

```
if (item.classList.contains('text-duedate')) {
    // this is not working
    item.remove();
}
```

**NOTE**
The `target` element is the element who clicked not who fired the event, so maybe a child element of it, I suggest you use `currentTarget`.

```
const item = e.currentTarget;
```

Comment: I just tried it and it still didn't work. And thank you for the 'contains' keyword. I haven't used that one before. I think its cleaner.

Comment: @user2816227, Also, make sure that the `item` is the `currentTarget` not `target` because `target` is the clicked element, not the element who fired the `event`

Comment: @user2816227, I update the answer, please check.

Comment: Mina, when I use e.currentTarget, My delete and check buttons stopped working.

Comment: @user2816227, could you provide a full example of the code, so we have a clearer look?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code and it seems to work fine

```
<div class="card-date">
    <span class="text-duedate">Due:</span>
    <span class="alert">9/12/22</span>
</div>
```

and JS

```
window.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const item = e.target;
    if (item.classList.contains('text-duedate')) {
        item.remove();
    }
})
```

Comment: sikriti dakua still doesn't work. There is something else preventing it from not running

Comment: can you create an example on jsFiddle and link it here

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/delo2795/fpt06eyv/3/

Comment: everything seems fine what functionality is not working on your end

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the help. This was the only way I could get it to work.

```
if (item.classList[0] === 'trash-btn') {
    const task = item.parentElement.parentElement;
    task.classList.add('vanish');
    // task.addEventListener('transition-end', function(){
    //     task.remove();
    // });
    task.remove();
}

let elems = document.querySelector('.text-duedate');
elems.remove();


if (item.classList.contains('check-btn')) {
    const task = item.parentElement.parentElement;
    completed.appendChild(task);
    item.remove();
    completed.addEventListener('click', statusCheck);

}
```